# I can start my Tomcat but unable to access localhost through browser

Tags: tomcat8

I can start my Tomcat through startup.bat and also through tomcat8.exe without any error in log files or in the console but unable to access localhost through browser. When trying to open the localhost, it is showing connection timed out. However I tried to open it again by increasing the timeout in xml file of tomcat. But this didn't work.

I tried to reinstall it but still the problem persists.

I tried to access the localhost through the telnet but there also getting 
Connection to Tomcat...Could not open connection to the host on the port : 9090 connect failed

Please help me out. Stuck in this matter for long time!!!

Logs created in localhsot.2016.04.17.log without any error.

Logs created in the Commons-daemons without any error.

However not getting any logs in the Manager and localhost_access logs may be because of the above issue.

Below environment variables set -
CATALINA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77
PATH : C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;H:\app\atulranjan\product\12.1.0\dbhome_2\bin;H:\app\atulranjan\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Windows\System32;%PATH%;H:\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin;

Comment: Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Assuming no config changes in tomcat. 8080 is the default port. Check catalina logs to verify on which port tomcat is listening.

Comment: 17-Apr-2016 15:24:12.749 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-9090"]
17-Apr-2016 15:24:12.765 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
17-Apr-2016 15:24:12.781 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 2553 ms 

What I can see is that it is listening to 9090, the port that I have changed. Thanks

Comment: Please help if someone can!!  Thanks